# How to set URL in selenium script that is set up to run Selenium Tests (C#) based on environment during CI/CD

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, nunit, devops

I have a Selenium Nunit Script which is set up to run whenever a build is deployed to VSTS.

I am unable to figure out a way on how to pass the URL of the environment to the selenium script based on the environment that the code has been deployed to.

Example:

When Code is  deployed to QA env, selenium script should select QA url and run the tests.

Similarly, when code is  deployed to UAT env, url inside the script should set to UAT specific url and run the tests.

How do i achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the parameter in setting file, then override the value by specifying in Override test run parameters box of visual studio test task.

[How do I pass parameters to my test code from a build or release pipeline?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/reference-qa?view=vsts#q-how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-my-test-code-from-a-build-or-release-pipeline)

On the other hand, you can define multiple variables with the same name and different scopes (environment) in release definition, then just read that variable's value from environment variable in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are kicking it off. You can pass custom parameters to NUnit via `--params` and then pull those in your code using `TestContext`. Rather than passing an entire URL, I would suggest that you just pass the environment, QA or UAT. Then in your code you can make decisions, set variables like URL, etc. based on the environment passed.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line#options

> --params|p=PARAMETER
>   A test PARAMETER specified in the form NAME=VALUE for consumption by tests. Multiple parameters may be specified, separated by semicolons or by repeating the --params option multiple times. Case-sensitive.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#testparameters

> Test parameters may be supplied to a run in various ways, depending on the runner used. For example, the console runner provides a command-line argument and v3.4 of the NUnit 3 VS Adapter will supports specifying them in a .runsettings file. The static TestParameters property returns an object representing those passed-in parameters.